Discord bot running on local machine, but when running on a web-server, my array returns empty
I'm using beautiful soup to scrape prices of cards, when running on my Macbook Air (M3), the program returns my array with the values expected. When running on a web server, my array returns empty. First time using python to this extent, so unsure if its the code or a machine issue.
I changed the website I was scraping, I checked to see if my encoding matches when running on both machines, both are utf-8.
website I scrapped: https://lorcanaplayer.com/lorcana-card-list/
Repo: https://github.com/Jonmoreno14/lorcana-python-bot
'PlyexNodes' as the server
r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
array = [item.get_text() for item in soup.findAll('span', class_="btn-price")]
newArr = [] #array with just prices
for i in array:
    pattern = re.compile(r'\-?\d+\.\d+')
    diffPrices = list(map(float, re.findall(pattern, i)))
    newArr.append(str(diffPrices))
            
print(array)
print(newArr)

Error:
ice block vs ice block
FOUNDDDDDDDDD
ice block
https://lorcanaplayer.com/lorcana-card-list/ice-block
https://lorcanaplayer.com/lorcana-card-list/ice-block
[]
[]
2024-05-29 12:43:43 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'cardsearch'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 138, in cardSearchResult
    await results(foundName)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 127, in results
    p1 = newArr[0]
         ~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'cardsearch' raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range


Are there any privilges you need to fetch data from the server? What is the web server you are using? We need more info about your deployement enviroment.

No privileges besides the token for logging in the bot.

I couldn't point out a direct problem with the extra information you provided. If it was a code issue it wouldn't work on your local machine. Also why did you delete the error information? Error Info
